# Change translated text in react-datepicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

I am using `react-datepicker` package for date and time picking. I am passing language dynamically to the datepicker via locale prop for setting the language of the date and time picker. For the time picker, when the locale is set as `de` it translates AM/PM to `vormittags/machmittags` based on the selected time. I want to change that to `Uhr` instead. But reading their documentation it seems to be not supported by default. I need some suggestions on if it's possible to achieve this somehow while using the package.

Here's the time picker code -

```
<DatePicker
 selected={time}
 readOnly={true}
 showTimeSelect
 shouldCloseOnSelect
 showTimeSelectOnly
 timeIntervals={15}
 timeCaption={t("AddNewEvent.time")}
 dateFormat="hh:mm aaaa"
 open={isTimepickerOpen}
 onClickOutside={handleToggleTimePicker}
 className="form-control"
 onChange={(value) => handleChange("time", value)}
 locale={i18n.language}
 />
```

[image]